# Tkinter - Require checkboxes to be marked in order

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, checkbox

I am trying to make a GUI with tkinter that is a checklist for operating a system.  Each step has to be done in order before moving on to the next step.  How to I set up the checkboxes such that each checkbox has to be marked before I can mark the next checkbox in the list?  For example, I have to mark the first checkbox before I can mark the second.

Comment: You can disable all checkboxes except the first one initially.  Then enable next checkbox after checking active checkbox.

Comment: I know how to disable the checkboxes but I am having trouble getting the next checkbox to automatically be enabled once I check off the enabled checkbox.  Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable all checkboxes except the first one initially.  Then enable next checkbox after current checkbox is checked.

Below is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def on_check(i):
    # disable current todo item
    checkbuttons[i].config(state="disabled", font="Arial 16 overstrike")
    # enable next todo item if any
    if i < len(checkbuttons)-1:
        checkbuttons[i+1].config(state="normal")
    else:
        print("All done!")

checkbuttons = []
for i in range(10):
    checkbuttons.append(tk.Checkbutton(root, text=f"ToDo {i+1}", font="Arial 16", state="normal" if i == 0 else "disabled"))
    checkbuttons[-1].grid(row=i)
    checkbuttons[-1].config(command=lambda i=i: on_check(i))

root.mainloop()
```